# A "non-degenerate pairing" between $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$ and $K/k$

Tags: galois-theory, homology-cohomology

In this post, I'd like to compare Galois theory and homology theory. Due to the limit of my knowledge, I'm not sure if my consideration is right. I hope you can show me the right way.

In topology, given a smooth manifold $M$, and $\Omega^n(M)$ be space of smooth real $n$-differential form, and $H^n(M)$ be $n$-dimensional de Rham cohomology group of $M$. Let $H_n(M)$ be singular homology group of $M$. Then there is a nondegenerate bilinear pairing
$$(\cdot ,\cdot ): H^n(M)\times H_n(M)\to \mathbb R$$
$$([ \omega ],[c ])\to \int_{\omega}c$$
where $[\omega]$ and $[c]$ are equivalent classes in $H^n(M)$ and $H_n(M)$, respectively.

Here, **nondegenerate** means two things:

1. Given $[\omega] \in H^n(M)$, if for every $[c]\in  H_n(M)$, the pairing $([\omega ],[c ])=0$, then $[\omega]$ is a trivial form
2. Given $[c] \in  H_n(M)$, if for every $[\omega]\in H^n(M)$, the pairing $([\omega ],[c ])=0$, then $[c]$ is a trivial $n$-chain.

In Galois theory, we have a similar "duality". Let $K/k$ be a finite field extension, and $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$ be corresponding Galois group. Theorems say that

1. Given $\alpha \in K$, if $\alpha$ is fixed by every $k$-automorphism $\sigma\in \operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$, then $\alpha \in k$
2. Given $k$-automorphism $\sigma \in  \operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$, if $\sigma$ fix every $\alpha \in K$, then $\sigma=\mathrm{id}_K$ is the identity element in $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$.

By comparison, the relationship between $\operatorname{Gal}(K/k)$ and $K/k$ is very similar to the relationship between $H^n(M)$ and $H_n(M)$. My question is that can we define a "nondegenerate" map like 
$$(\cdot ,\cdot ): \operatorname{Gal}(K/k)\times K \to K $$
$$(\sigma ,\alpha)\to \sigma(\alpha)$$

I'm not sure if my consideration is right. Further, is there any category description of the such relationship?

Comment: The general category-theoretic tool you want is called a Galois connection, which is a pair of adjoint functors between two posets. A nondegenerate bilinear pairing $V \otimes W \to \mathbb{R}$ induces a Galois connection between subspaces of $V$ and subspaces of $W$; similarly, the Galois correspondence induces a Galois connection between subgroups of the Galois group and subextensions of the Galois extension. In both cases the adjoint functors involved are contravariant.